# YouTube GDATA playlist feed of user containing spaces

Tags: youtube, feed, gdata

I am using:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/johndoe/playlists?alt=json

to parse the json object.

However this works only if the user is a single word.

How to make this feed work for users that have multiple words in their names?

Example:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/JOHN DOE/playlists?alt=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, spaces are not allowed in youtube user ID.

Where spaces are allowed (for example in search query), they are encoded as `%20` as usual in http requests:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json&q=dogs%20cats
```